# WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" when Owner is null

Tags: c#, wpf

How exactly the `WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"` works if the Owner window is null? Is it possible to change somehow this behaviour (preferably globally in an application and not on each window) ?

In my application I have several dialogs (most of them help to change some of the application's configuration / settings), which I either show before defining the `Application.Current.MainWindow` or after. For example, on application startup I display a windows where someone can select the application language. I display the exact same through application setting pane / window.

I want this language selection window to be appeared

- on the center of the screen when is called on application startup, thus `Application.Current.MainWindow` is null and selection window has no owner
- on the center of its parent / owner windows when it is called from application setting pane / window

The `WindowStartupLocation` is the property that defines the location of the window. However if I set `WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"` and the owner is null the window will be displayed at the left upper corner of my screen.

Until now I have an if statement in 'every' window constructor that check if owner is null and changes the `WindowStartupLocation`.

```
if (dialog.Owner == null && dialog.WindowStartupLocation == WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner)
{
    dialog.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it? For example instruct framework to handle it. Set something like fallback values for WindowStartupLocation, e.g if the owner is null then `WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"`

Comment: A dialog *must* have an owner.  If you don't give it one then a lot more can go wrong beyond its location.  You can easily have Z-order problems with the dialog, or the window you display after closing the dialog, disappearing behind the window of another app.  Particularly painful for a dialog since it doesn't (shouldn't) have a taskbar button.

Comment: @HansPassant Understood, but when I am showing a window from `App.xaml.cs` (application startup), which is its owner? As I am saying in my question if this window has `WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"` it will be displayed at the left upper corner of my screen. So I assume that its owner is `null`

Comment: You can define base class for "dialog" windows and encapsulate `WindowStartupLocation` selection in base constructor

Comment: @AlekseyL. This (move logic to a base class) will be the next step of what I am currently doing and the best solution so far. However I want to avoid this manual switching with the if condition.